# Does typescript always assumes side effects are not allowed?

Tags: typescript, mutation, side-effects

I have the following toy example where typescript warns me of an error:

```
type obj = {
    ok: "ok" | "error",
}

function main(a: obj){
    a.ok = "ok";
    reloadFromDatabase(a);
    if (a.ok == "error"){ // TS error 
        console.log("Error");
    }
}

// Any function that has side effects on object a.
// For example, typeorm's `a.reload()`
function reloadFromDatabase(a: obj){
    a.ok = "error";
}
```

The error is:

```
This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"ok"' and '"error"' have no overlap.(2367)
```

It makes sense if you assume side effect that mutate objects are not allowed, but the type of `a` is `obj` so it should allow both values (`"ok" | "error"`) for `obj.isOk`.

In this particular code example where I have my hands on the function that has side effects its fine because I could just return the mutated object:

```
function main(a: obj){
    a.ok = "ok";
    a = reloadFromDatabase(a);
    if (a.ok == "error"){ // This time its fine
        console.log("Error");
    }
}

function reloadFromDatabase(a: obj){
    a.ok = "error";
    return a;
}
```

But in my usecase I don't have access to the `reloadFromDatabase` and it returns nothing (it just mutate the object).

Is that a typescript option? Does it seems like a legitimate error? Am I missing a case where allowing mutation would completely break typescript logic (offer less/no type safety)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the trade-offs made in control flow analysis:

You can have a look at this famous issue : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

It can summed up as the question :

> The primary question is: When a function is invoked, what should we
> assume its side effects are?

And right now, TS assume there are no side effects.

The work around for this is to use a type assertion :

```
if (a.ok as obj['ok'] == "error") { // ok asserted as 'ok'|'error'
   console.log("Error");
}
```

Comment: Not the DV but this answer is skirting the boundary of being link-only, especially before you added the workaround code block. Maybe add a little sizzle from the linked github thread here in the text of the answer?

Comment: You're right, the answer ought to be a bit better

Comment: Summarizing this huge thread was indeed important to me. The workaround does indeed [solve my problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA9gRgKygXigbwFBW7A1gLigCIZcioAfYiAJxphqIBoMBfDDAMwFcA7AY2ABLGLygBbAIZDeACkmF4CAJSYcUSQDpSKYqSIBuLDhoQANjEkATAGL1xAEUnBJcSQGcI85UfVDOUPLauCioRLT0jKrG6tj8ou4wZhCaFgDmskQAonQMRD4xUOx+AUE6HrCIANoA5KQ1ALqh1LlRarFxCUkp6Zk5kfm+OOzsXHyCImKmFtZ2MI7Orh5eCpUq7dhaOmEReUbsQA).

Comment: Maybe that would be interesting to have an example of what breaks if this assumption is not made (to have a feel about the compromise being done here)?